# How to properly set pointers to an array with chars in it

Tags: arrays, c, char, scanf, pointer-arithmetic

I hope some of you may help me with a basic understanding of pointers assigned to an array with chars in it (specifically letters). My problem is that part of my code when the user is supposed to input letters, 'D' or 'U'  doesn't work and I don't know exactly where the problem is. I was trying to set it without pointers but that made my program more complicated and I'm also trying to finally learn that goddamn thing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int number;

   scanf("%d", &number);
   char *pz;
   char save[number];
  

   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
   {
       pz = &save[i];
       scanf("%s", pz+i);
   }
```

Comment: You cannot `scanf` a number and then create an array of that size without dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: This code does not make any sense. Please explain what this program is supposed to do

Comment: @whiskeyo No, he can if the compiler allows to do that.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that instead of this

```
   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
   {
       pz = &save[i];
       scanf("%s", pz+i);
   }
```

you mean

```
   for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
   {
       pz = save + i;
       scanf( " %c", pz );
   }
```

Pay attention to the blank in the format string `" %c"`.

The pointer `pz`  already points to the desired position in the array

```
pz = save + i;
```

So using the expression `pz+i` in the call of `scanf` does not make a sense.

And instead of the conversion specifier `%s` you have to use the conversion specifier `%c`.

After inputting the character array you can output it like

```
printf( "%.*s\n", number, save );
```

Or you can output the array in a loop like for example

```
   for ( pz = save; pz != save + number; ++pz )
   {
       putchar( *pz );
   }
   putchar( '\n' );
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. I am just a beginner in C and I can see that I have a lot of work ahead of myself. Thank you very much for your help.